# apache solr does not load mysql data into core

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene

i'm using apache solr version 6.4.1 on windows 10 .i want to load data from mysql database into solr core but it does not works.
here is the scenario : there is a core named ako in directory **\solr-6.4.1\solr-6.4.1\server\solr** and files **solrconfig.xml & db-data-config.xml** in directory **\solr-6.4.1\solr-6.4.1\server\solr\ako\conf** . i added needed lines of code to **solrconfig.xml** as below :

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler> 

<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-6.4.1.jar" />
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-extras-6.4.1.jar" />
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
```

and below is content of file **db-data-config.xml**:

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/meeva" user="root" password=""/>
    <document>
    <entity name="businesses" query="select id, title from businesses">
        <field column="id" name="biz_id" />
        <field column="title" name="biz_title" />
    </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

i added **scema.xml** file with this below content , but still does not work:

```
<field name="biz_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

<field name="biz_title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

but when importing data from solr admin page ( go to **http://localhost:8983/solr/#/ako/dataimport//dataimport?command=full-import**)
it returns **Requests: 0 , Fetched: 0 , Skipped: 0 , Processed: 0**
and nothing is added to core.can anyone help please?

Comment: do you have the schema.xml?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti no i have not? and i don,t know how to use it

Comment: could you please check the below links https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler

Comment: i'll check it ...thanks

Comment: one more https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/apache-solr/solr-dataimporthandler-example/

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti i checked those tutorials and made some changes to  config files but still does not fetch any data

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to have `solr-dataimporter` handler enabled. You need to enable `mysql-connector` as well.
Go to mysql archives: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-j/
Choose version close to date release of your Solr version.
Download it, and copy .jar file, e.g. `mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar` to your solr libs directory (probably, this is `/dist` directory under your solr installation path).

You got to restart Solr service to apply this.